# Facebook api login success but not return success paper

Tags: c#, facebook, windows-phone-7, facebook-graph-api, windows-phone-8

i am writing a windows phone game with facebook integrated. I have a problem.

After I logged in with right username/password. It showed:

> "... would like to access your public profile...".

And I press Ok. Then another message:

> ".... would like to post on your behalf".

And OK. It navigated to `m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/write` - a blank paper. No success paper or access token returned.
Then I debugged again. After logged in, It navigated to Success paper and access token.

My question is why? Are there some way to skip `.... would like to post on your behalf` message.

---

This is my code

```
private void myWeb_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        parameters["client_id"] = appID;
        parameters["redirect_uri"] = "https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html";
        parameters["response_type"] = "token";
        parameters["display"] = "popup";
        parameters["scope"] = extendedPermissions;

        Uri loginUri = _fbClient.GetLoginUrl(parameters);

        this.myWeb.Navigate(loginUri);
    }
```

and

```
private void myWeb_Navigated(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Uri.AbsoluteUri);
        //myText.Text = e.Uri.AbsoluteUri;
        FacebookOAuthResult oauthResult;
        if (_fbClient.TryParseOAuthCallbackUrl(e.Uri, out oauthResult))
        {
            if (oauthResult.IsSuccess)
            {
                AccessToken = oauthResult.AccessToken;

                MessageBox.Show("Login success!\n" + AccessToken);
                NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/TestPape.xaml?token="+AccessToken, UriKind.Relative));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // The url is NOT the result of OAuth 2.0 authentication.
            return;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Show us some code that you used for login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Are there some way to skip .... would like to post on your behalf

You have added the permission `publish_action`/`publish_stream` while login, that's why it's showing you the second permission window. If in your application, you are posting feed on the users' behalf you required those permissions to be granted by the user; BUT if you don't want to post anything; you can remove those permissions.

Comment: I tried remove those permission. No second permission window and It still navigated to "m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/write" with blank paper.

Comment: Don't use this way to login, its suited for the web. Follow this link- http://facebooksdk.net/. Very simple steps, examples and nice way of integrating the facebook with your app. PS. pls accept this answer if helped. Cheers!

Comment: I solved it. I missing IsScriptEnabled="True" in LoginPape.xaml